# Python: Filter List of Coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance

Hello i have the following problem. I have a list of tuples, where each tuple consists of 3D coordinates. Every coordinate is at another time step. They are really close together. Is there a possibiity to maniupulate/filter the list, so that there are only coordinates which have for example a distance of 1?. So for example i have

```
list1=[(x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2),(x3,y3,z3),(x4,y4,z4),(x5,y5,z5),(x6,y6,z6)
```

and the filter would produce

```
list2=[(x1,y1,z1),(x3,y3,z3),(x4,y4,z4),(x6,y6,z6)],
```

because `(x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2)` and `(x4,y4,z4),(x5,y5,z5)` are too close.

Comment: Are you referring specifically to adjacent tuples in the list, as opposed to any pairs anywhere in the list that are within a distance of 1?

Comment: ALso, how would you define "closeness"?

Comment: You may want to read this: [Closest pair algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem)

Comment: The distance should be the eucledean distance, and I think it should check for example tuple 1 and 2, if the distance is greater or equal 1 than they are written to list2, if the distance is smaller, then tuple2 is discarded. Then tuple 1 and 3 have to be checked. As long the distance of coordinates to tuple1 is smaller than 1 it has to be compared to the following tuples and so on

Comment: What is the expected size of the vectors set? Is it relatively small for a naive n^2 algorithm, or requires an efficient algorithm?

Comment: @Elisha There are between 50 and 100 coordinates in a list which has to be filtered

Comment: I don't think your proposed approach can work. In 3D space, just because tuple2 was within a distance of 1 from tuple1, it doesn't mean it would be within a distance of 1 from tuple3 - they could be on opposite sides of tuple1. This error will propagate as you go further along the list.

Comment: @roganjosh The move in one direction, so it is ok

Answer (score 1):

Since the size of the vectors set is small (<100), a simple solution can be used. The following code chooses representatives from the set, as long as they are not close to an existing representative already chosen. This code is naive in the in regard to performance and it is sensitive to the order of the tuples. According to the question comments, it may fit the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

def predicate(representatives, vector):
    return all(euclidean(representative, vector) >= 1
               for representative in representatives)



def main():
    vectors = [tuple(l) for l in np.random.random_integers(0, 5, (100, 3))]

    representatives = set()
    for vector in vectors:
        if predicate(representatives, vector):
            representatives.add(vector)
```

On my machine (i5 with 6GB) it takes ~100ms.